# Is there a way to connect Custom Translator with Speech Translation?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I want to find the way how can I connect [Speech Translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-translation) with [Custom Translator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/customization/).

On Custom Translator webpage there is mentioned that: "Custom Translator can be used for customizing text when using the Microsoft Translator Text API , **and speech translation using the Microsoft Speech services**."

Unfortunatelly, I didn't find any example of that usage.

Can anyone help with that?

Thank you!

Comment: Can’t find it either

Answer (score 0):

If you build your application based on this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-translate-speech-cpp-windows),

You can set the category id at the SpeechTranslationConfig as follows:

config->SetServiceProperty("category", "", ServicePropertyChannel.UriQueryParameter);

This is available since Microsoft Speech SDK 1.5. [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cognitive-services/speech/translation-speechtranslationconfig)